# How to use string array in firebase while using "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have some string array values for email and password in my string.xml in android application. how to use those values in "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)"

```
    <string-array name="test_email">
        <item>arzonefour@gmail.com</item>
        <item>mamarzad421@gmail.com</item>
        <item>shadhir1854@gmail.com</item>
        <item>pluto@gmail.com</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="test_password">
    <item>mar6677214</item>
    <item>arzad123</item>
    <item>shadhir123</item>
    <item>pluto</item>
</string-array>
```

This is my java code

```
 private void loginToFirebase() {

String email[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test_email);
String password[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test_password);


   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {


            if (task.isSuccessful()) {



                requestLocationUpdates();
            } else {



                Log.d(TAG, "Firebase authentication failed");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

but it give me an error when i use email and password as parameter

[this is the error i am getting when i use array as parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDi0b.png)

Comment: What is it that you expect the API to do with a string array when it's clearly demanding a single string?

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve, to sign-in multiple users? Please also responde with @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only sign in with a single user account at a time. So to sign in with the first user from your XML, you'd do:

```
String email[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test_email);
String password[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test_password);

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email[0], password[0]).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
```